# New to JavaScript, coming from Python, why is it not working?

Tags: javascript, function

the print is not working.

```js
const print = console.log();

print("Hello World")
```

anyone have any ideas what is going on? I am trying to make a print function in JavaScript. I come from a Python environment... Please help me with this. I appreciate any help from someone who know how to solve this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `console.log();` returns `undefined` ... i.e. your code runs `console.log()` and the returned value is assigned to `const print` -if you want `print` to do the same as `console.log` then ... assign it the value of `console.log` ... not what it returns (or wait until someone spoon feeds you the solution)

Comment: const print = console.log

Comment: Get used to writing `console.log`. Don't force one language's idioms on other languages.

Comment: FYI, the Python equivalent to your code would be `p = print()` `p('Hello')`. And you might see why that doesn't work…?

Comment: @deceze interesting duplicate but I think `console.log()` has evolved to no longer be required to be called on the `console` context

Comment: @Phil Yes, but I don't know if there's any guarantee to that across all platforms. Also, you can't generalise from this `console.log` example to all other methods, so understanding binding is still important, or you'll trip over it later. And lastly, the dupe contains a sample of the *correct* code.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers. This is actually just a question I created for experimenting StackOverflow for something I want to make. Thanks again for taking your time to help me out. I know this isn't a valid syntax but it is a fun way to see others opinions on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on doing it the wrong way, here's what you can do:

```js
const print = console.log
print("Hello World")
```

But the right way of doing it, is:

```js
console.log("Hello World")
```

Some explanation: `console.log` is a *function*, but `console.log()` is the stuff that the function returns, which in this case, it's *undefined*. So if you want to save a reference to the function, you should use `console.log`.